# Get the cell address of maximum column and row containing the most right and bottom value

Tags: google-sheets

I want to grab the address of the cell of the most right and bottom value. This image should explain it. yellow is the the most right value. and the green is most bottom value. And the orange is the target cell.

Is it possible using formula? something like combining getLastRow() and getLastColumn() when using google script.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give a text string like `U17` when used from *another* sheet:

```
=arrayformula( 
  address( 
    max( if( len(Sheet1!A1:ZZZ), row(Sheet1!A1:ZZZ) ) ), 
    max( if( len(Sheet1!A1:ZZZ), column(Sheet1!A1:ZZZ) ) ), 
    4 
  ) 
)
```

You cannot use the formula on the sheet you are measuring because it will give a circular reference error.

Comment: Awesome. This is what i'm looking for.